# Is there a tool that takes binary serialized .Net data and construct a class file that maps to it?

Tags: .net

I have a .dat file that contains .Net binary serialized data for the old .Net Remoting binary serialized format.  What I do not have is a class definition for it.

Is there an app or API that can take a serialized data file, read it and create .Net class file that can then be used within an application to deserialize the object, modify the results and resave it to date file?

I have found the serialization spec, and I could possibly write one myself that could reverse-engineer the file, but the need isn't that great for that amount of time.  Considering that the spec outlines fields and data times defined within the serialized file, certainly someone has created a tool to reverse engineer this data to classes, without the need of an existing C# class definition.